# Start Timer in GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a problem with the GridView.

I would like to have a Grid with pictures and under each of them should be a timer. When I click one of the images, there should start the timer bellow of it.

How can I adapt TextViews and Images to a Gridview and let the TextView change every second.

I changed my code now to this

MainActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable{
    /** The Constant INTERVALL. */
    private static final int INTERVALL = 1000;

    private ImageAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> listText;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listImage;
    private GridView gridView;

    /** The handler. */
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    public boolean timerRuns = false;
    public int time ;
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid);

        //GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        //gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        prepareList();

        // prepared arraylist and passed it to the Adapter class
        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, listText, listImage);

        // Set custom adapter to gridview
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Implement On Item click listener
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mAdapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        chronometer();
    }

    public void startTimer(View v) {
        timerRuns = true;
        time = 5*60;
        update();
        this.handler.postDelayed(this, INTERVALL);
    }

    public void stopTimer(View v) {
        timerRuns = false;
        handler.removeCallbacks(this);
    }


    public void chronometer(){
        time = time -1;
        update();
        handler.postDelayed(this, INTERVALL);
    }

    private void update(){
        updateScreen();
    }

    private void updateScreen(){
        //TextView tvChronometer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvChronometer);
        //tvChronometer.setText(Integer.toString(time));
    }







        public void prepareList()
        {
            listText = new ArrayList<String>();

            listText.add("Sample");
            listText.add("Brazil");
            listText.add("Canada");
            listText.add("China");
            listText.add("France");
            listText.add("Germany");
            listText.add("Iran");
            listText.add("Italy");
            listText.add("Japan");
            listText.add("Korea");
            listText.add("Mexico");
            listText.add("Netherlands");
            listText.add("Portugal");
            listText.add("Russia");
            listText.add("Saudi Arabia");
            listText.add("Spain");
            listText.add("Turkey");
            listText.add("United Kingdom");
            listText.add("United States");

            listImage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_0);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_3);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_3);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_7);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_1);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_6);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_2);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_7);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_4);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_5);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_0);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_5);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_0);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_2);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_1);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_4);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_3);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_1);
            listImage.add(R.drawable.sample_6);
        }

    }
```

The ImageAdapter

```
`public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<String> listText;
private ArrayList<Integer> listImage;
private Activity activity;

public ImageAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<String> listText, ArrayList<Integer> listImage) {
    super();
    this.listText = listText;
    this.listImage = listImage;
    this.activity = activity;
}



@Override
public int getCount() {

    return listText.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {

    return listText.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView imgView;
    public TextView txtView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder view;
    LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        view = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.element, null);

        view.txtView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eText);
        view.imgView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eImage);

        convertView.setTag(view);
    }
    else
    {
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    view.txtView.setText(listText.get(position));
    view.imgView.setImageResource(listImage.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

}`
my gridview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="110dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
/>
```

and my element.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/eImage"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:src="@color/Bisque" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" >
</TextView>
```

```
I hope you can help me.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Creating a gridview with text and image in each cell**

Take a look at the documentation for GridView:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

The key method there is the `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`

That method returns a view for each cell in the grid. You can create an XML layout that includes the TextView and ImageView. In the getView method for the adapter inflate the XML layout, attach an onClickListener so you can start the timer and return it as a view.

**2. Updating the TextView from the grid**

Keep in mind that a gridview contains contains multiple views, each of which can come from the same resource so this: `TextView tvChronometer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvChronometer);` is not going to work in a gridview.

What you need to do is to get the specific view from the cell that you need (or iterate through all of them) and update the view. Something like this:

```
//First get the view for the cell assuming it's a composite view
View cellView = (TextView) gridview.getChildAt(position);

//Then get the actual TextView from that grid cell
TextView tvChronometer = cellView.findViewById(R.id.tvChronometer);
```

Although the best way in my opinion is to save a reference to the TextView when you a creating/instantiating it in the adapter.

Comment: I tried similar things. The problem was always I couldn't make the TextView change

Comment: How can I adapt the Textview in the Grid? With the Imageadapter? If its so how can I do it? I tried a lot of things but nothing worked

Comment: Yes, you can create/update the TextView with any class that extends the BaseAdapter. I can't help you much without knowing more about the problems you are having and seeing the rest of the code. I suggest you take a look at a few gridview tutorials available online: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/ and http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

Comment: Can you help me again? Now there is my code in the question so you can help mke maybe